# Slang"put your guns on"

Tags: grammaticality, slang

Would you like to tell me what does this slang mean?"put your guns on"anyone gets it?

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: It *could* mean "get ready for a fight"  but without some context it's anyone's guess

Comment: When i was watching an anime which is preparing for the school festival and the prez asks the students"put your guns on"

Comment: I'm flagging this as unclear, as there's insufficient information to offer a definitive answer. Mari, have you thought to ask the "Prez" what they meant?

Comment: @Chappo - it's anime.

Comment: @Jim aha. So even the comments are unclear! If it was said within an anime, then we have to include the possibility it has an entirely literal meaning. Mari, please don't provide further information via *comments* - instead, you need to [edit] your **question** to add the details we need so that we can understand what the intention of the expression was.

Comment: Anyone who had watched a US "western" from the 1950s would understand it with no difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

See this video...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTkLA-5j0AA
"ARE YOU READY GUYS!? PUT YA GUNS ON!"
=> Ready to fight, to run, to start a battle, a new challenge!

The opposite is "Put your gun down". 
Se the Lyric Put Your Gun Down by Oceana  @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8E-y_8M1OnQ

Tonight, 
Don’t fight, 
I surrender,
So, Put your Gun Down

Tonight, 
Don’t fight, 
Love stronger,
So, put your gun down. 
(OCEANA)

Congrats,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

From the American Wild West!  [**Encyclopedia of Texas** page 275](https://books.google.com/books?id=RePkhLzUjlEC&lpg=PA275&dq=%22get%20your%20guns%22%20dictionary&pg=PA275#v=onepage&q=%22get%20your%20guns%22%20dictionary&f=false)

> Everybody **get your guns ready**!" The recorded death toll was 3 sheriffs
>   and 19 citizens.

Not slang, nor is it idiomatic but redolent of all westerns ( movies shows etc ... aka *Annie Get Your Gun*).  And "**Johnnie get your gun**, get your gun, get your gun," urged George M. Cohan in his 1917 song, "Over There. ... Inc., 1916).

Meaning get ready, be prepared to fight!